# Selecting/Saving a group of calendar dates in QML

Tags: database, qt, firebase, calendar, qml

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store my user data.

Database entries are created by saving dates from the `calendar.selectedDate`.

My problem is each time the user has to select the date and press the save button which isn't very fluid.

I am wondering if it's possible to select/highlight multiple dates at once to then batch save, or use a datePicker for a range?

My calendar is based off the QtQuick Controls 1 Calendar linked below,

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols1-calendar-example.html

I have searched around some and there doesn't seem to be a native datePicker and i'm wondering if there would be a workaround for the multiple highlight of date cells as I would also like to see a visual track of currently selected dates?

Comment: The standard control has property [selectedDate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html#selectedDate-prop) to set/get selected data and so that allows only single selection. But nobody forbids you to implement your own logic, to store multiple dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save multiple dates at once whilst maintaining the option for individual date saves using I have used an `AppCheckBox`, with a visual marker on each date as you navigate to show selected dates, I have used the below code along with the [Qt Quick Controls Calendar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html) as a basis

**Code:**

```
Page {
     id: calendarPage

     property var multiSelectArr: [] //where I store the selected date range

     AppCheckBox {
         id: dateRangeButton
         text: "date range"
     } // used to toggle multiple selection or single date

    Flow {
        Calendar {
            id: calendar
            selectedDate: new Date()

            onSelectedDateChanged: {
            dateRangeButton.checked ? multiSelectArr.push(calendar.selectedDate.getTime()) : multiSelectArr = [] // if dateRangeButton is not checked, empty array, otherwise add newly selected date

            multiSelectArrChanged() // this is where the magic happens, it triggers the array to update thus adding the new coloured marker to the date
            // without this, the highlight will not appear. 
            }
        //remainder of calendar code

           Rectangle {
           id: multiSelectMarker
           color: "green"
           visible: multiSelectArr.indexOf(styleData.date.getTime()) > -1 //check for date within array to show marker
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a great date picker here [Fluid](https://github.com/lirios/fluid) , download this extract it some where
open CMD or Terminal (in case you using linux) :
cd to folder where you extracted files
 `cd E:\fluid-develop\fluid-develop`
if you have currect enviroment variables for Qt (`C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\msvc2017\bin`) run these on cmd:

```
//this is how i installed it, in case this does not work there is installation guide at fluid page
qmake 
nmake //this comes with visual studio you can install mingw if you dont have it (for mingw its 'make')
nmake install
```

after this you should have a directory of this control inside your qml folder :

```
Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\msvc2017\qml\Fluid
```

now you have fluid controls you can create datetimepicker :

```
property var array: []
        Button{
            onClicked: {
                datePickerDialog.open()
                console.log(array)
            }
        }

        FluidControls.DatePickerDialog {
              id: datePickerDialog
              standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok | DialogButtonBox.Cancel
              standardButtonsContainer: Button {
                  anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                  text: qsTr("add to array")
                  flat: true
                  onClicked: {
                      var year = Qt.formatDateTime(datePickerDialog.selectedDate,"yyyy")
                      var month = Qt.formatDateTime(datePickerDialog.selectedDate,"MM")
                      var day = Qt.formatDateTime(datePickerDialog.selectedDate,"dd")
                      array.push(year+'-'+month+'-'+day)

                  }


              }
          }
```

and documentation for [this](https://liri.io/docs/sdk/fluid/develop/qml-fluid-controls-datetimepickerdialog.html)

Comment: Your post doesn't answer to the question of TC.

Comment: @folibis you might wanna check it again, i just tested this its working, if you want visual effects too for picker thats another question

Comment: It can work perfectly without any doubt but your example doesn't answer to the TS question - how to implement multiple data selection.

Comment: @folibis if you look to my code, i have an array of selected dates , which by pressing a button i push selected dates into that (i.e multiple date selecting for datepicker)